# Could not get unknown property for object of type DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer in Jenkins using Gradle plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, nexus

I'm trying to execute a gradle build script in Jenkins. This script has a task section like this:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'https://mynexus.com/repository/maven-releases/') {
               authentication(userName: nexusReleaseUser, password: nexusReleasePassword)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: 'https://mynexus.com/repository/maven-snapshots/') {
                authentication(userName:nexusSnapshotsUser, password:nexusSnapshotsPassword)}
            }
        }
}
```

Where nexusReleaseUser, nexusReleasePassword, nexusSnapshotsUser and nexusSnapshotsPassword are properties defined in gradle.properties.

This script works perfectly on my local machine, but fails in Jenkins.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':XXXXXXX'.
 > Could not get unknown property 'nexusReleaseUser' for object of type
org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.
```

I added those properties to Jenkins Gradle plugin configuration and in the jenkins console I could see them defined:

```
gradle -PnexusSnapshotsPassword=XXXXX -PnexusSnapshotsUser=XXXX -PnexusReleaseUser=XXXX -PnexusReleasePassword=XXXX clean buildAll -b build.gradle
```

Even if a put a:

```
println nexusReleaseUser
```

works perfectly and prints the value assigned to the property... but when using the propertie in the authentication part of maven deployer is not working at all

Can you help me?